# IndexError? what is it and how to fix it

Tags: python, database, image

i'm new to python and this code that i about to display just got from http://pythonprogramming.net/automated-image-thresholding-python/?completed=/thresholding-python-function/,
i get this error:

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/thresholding logic.py", line 15
    avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/thresholding logic.py", line 21
    if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/thresholding logic.py", line 41, in <module>
    iar = threshold(iar)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/thresholding logic.py", line 25, in threshold
    eachPix[3] = 0
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

how can i fix it and what is wrong with it?

this is my python 2.7 code on windows..

```
# if you are on 32 bit OS:
#import Image

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def threshold (imageArray):
    balanceAr = []
    newAr = imageArray

    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
    balance = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, balanceAr)/len(balanceAr)

    for eachRow in newAr:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
                eachPix[3] = 0

            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0
                eachPix[3] = 255

    return newAr

i = Image.open ('C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/50.0.png')
iar = np.array(i)

i2 = Image.open ('C:/Users/User/Desktop/tolong aku/50.1.png')
iar2 = np.array(i2)

iar = threshold(iar)
iar2 = threshold(iar2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,0), rowspan=4, colspan=3)

ax1.imshow(iar)
ax2.imshow(iar2)

plt.show()
```

i want to make the image turn to gray pixel and then collect the array results to make a data set..tq.

Comment: i'm actually just a beginner in python.i already read some python basic such as http://www.python-course.eu/course.php , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm , https://samarthbhargav.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/image-processing-with-python-rgb-to-grayscale-conversion/.so,i'm very sorry for asking such typical question like this.very appreciate all the helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index errors appear when you try to fetch an element of a sequence (eg. a list or a tuple), and use an index out of the range of the existing elements.

Eg.

```
t = (1, 2, 3)     # has elements at indices 0, 1, and 2
```

if you try to access element 3 or 4, you will get an index error. Only elements t[0], t[1], and t[2] exist.

> [[[ 78 84 84] [172 181 181] [188 196 198] ..., [111 116 113] [ 62 65
>   62] [ 64 66 63]] then, i can only use how many pix?

means that the inner index can count to 2: elements [0], [1], and [2].
The next index can go from 0 to (the number of triplets - 1)

Comment: so,is it mean that my array's data if it contain elements like this, [[[ 78  84  84]
  [172 181 181]
  [188 196 198]
  ..., 
  [111 116 113]
  [ 62  65  62]
  [ 64  66  63]]

then, i can only use how many pix?

Comment: ok,so i did change the [3] to [2] then, why the output image display only blue and white colour?can i change it to gray pixels?or can i just keep the blue image to usefor the whole data?

Comment: Well, I don't know how your colors are organized. if [172 181 181] means [red=172 green=181 blue=181] then you should probably remove the last assignment (`eachPix[3] = xxx`) NOT just change the index - you are overwriting the blue color component (or whatever last color).

Comment: just need to make the whole variables to [0] and then another to [255],eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255

            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0